# Access violation on c++ methods launched from DllImport

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport, access-violation

I have strange problem about some methods, which is launched from DllImport.

In native c++ I have code:

```
#define BUFSIZE 4096

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wchar_t *tekst = L"D:\\matiz\\Dokumenty\\!FIRMA TRIM-POT\\Firmowe";
    PrintTekst(tekst);
}

bool PrintTekst(wchar_t *tekst)
{   
    DWORD  retval = 0;
    BOOL   success;
    TCHAR  buffer[BUFSIZE] = TEXT("");
    TCHAR  buf[BUFSIZE];
    TCHAR** lppPart = { NULL };
    retval = GetFullPathNameW(tekst, BUFSIZE, buffer, lppPart);
    return true;
}

bool __stdcall PrintTekstExtern(wchar_t *tekst)
{
    return PrintTekst(tekst);
}
```

When I call **PrintTekst** method direct from main function everything is ok, but when I call this method using DllImport, on line:

```
TCHAR  buffer[BUFSIZE] = TEXT("");
```

I have **Access Violation Exception**. It's very strange situation, because in fact I don't use any arguments, which come from manager code in this case.

Method, which is launched in c#:

```
[DllImport("Pointers.exe", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool PrintTekstExtern(string tekst);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string cos = @"D:\matiz\Dokumenty\visual studio 2013\Projects\Pointers\PointersSharp\bin\Debug";
    var status = PrintTekstExtern(cos);
}
```

}

Could you help me?

Comment: why don't you make it a DLL instead of exe?

Comment: Please see this link it may help you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7fd652c-7875-43da-bfd9-b8c02201ad84/dllimport-exe-how-to-initialize-runtime-library

Answer (score 0):

The big problem is that you are trying to import a function from an executable rather than a DLL. That's the first thing to fix, and the real cause of your fatal crash.

Beyond that, the unmanaged function is:

```
bool __stdcall PrintTekstExtern(wchar_t *tekst)
```

Your p/invoke is:

```
[DllImport("...", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, 
    CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool PrintTekstExtern(string tekst);
```

There is one minor problem here. The return value is marshalled as a 4 byte boolean type, but the unmanaged code uses a 1 byte type. Read about that here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/14/pinvoke-and-bool-or-should-i-say-bool.aspx

Fix that by changing the p/invoke like so:

```
[DllImport("...", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, 
    CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
public static extern bool PrintTekstExtern(string tekst);
```

I would also suggest using `CharSet.Unicode` since the unmanaged code uses `wchar_t` and is therefore explicit about using 16 bit text.

Comment: also they need to specify the marshaling on the string, and export it from the DLL using `extern "C"` so it's not name mangled

Comment: @Mgetz The string is fine. I suspect that a .def file is used and so the function is exported undecorated.

Comment: That may be, in my experience the P/Invoke least likely to fail and most like to be performant is the one that leaves very little to the marshaller to guess at

Comment: @Mgetz There's no guessing here. `CharSet.Auto` is clear, although as I said I would prefer `CharSet.Unicode`.